# HtmlEncode with HTML entity name, is it possible?

Tags: c#, html-entities, html-encode

I am using the following method to `HtmlEncode` some `text` that it's in `Spanish`, like this:

```
string word = "configuración";
string encodedWord = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode(word);
```

The output is the expected:

```
configuraci&#243;n
```

But! the `&#243;` text represents the **HTML entity number** for a latin small letter "o" with acute.

However, I want to know if there is a way - using a built-in function which I don't know, library, etc - to show the **HTML entity name of the HTML entity number** and also support other characters (like a generic solution).

What I've tried so far is to check for a HTML entities table (there were many when Googling but I used this one: http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm) then created a custom `method` for replacing the needed `string` from the word by doing some mapping.

So, if the word contains `&#243;` then the matching text will be replaced to it's **HTML entity name** which is `oacute;` but it is really painful since there are plenty of cases/scenarios.

Finally, the desired output will be:

```
configuraci&oacute;n
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HtmlEncode(word); does only encode [ISO 8859-1 (Latin-1)](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/entities.html#iso-88591). Which means your input needs to be encoded in ISO 8859-1. The ó is not in the iso standard, you can try to use the AntiXss encoder:

```
Microsoft.Security.Application.AntiXss.HtmlEncode("ó"); 

or Microsoft.Security.Application.Encoder.HtmlEncode("ó");
```

Comment: Sorry, I can't use this since I am under a console app and I think this is not related at all with *encoding*, really.

Comment: I've updated the answer, you can test if AntiXss HtmlEncode can handle the ó.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the hint! however using `Microsoft.Security.Application.AntiXss.HtmlEncode` is deprecated. The right one to use is the following: `Microsoft.Security.Application.Encoder.HtmlEncode` and setting to `true` the second argument of the constructor makes the html encode to show the named entities that I was looking for :-)