# C# HtmlEncode name only

Tags: c#, html, ascii, encode

According to [this](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm) table, I need to Encode a string in C# the following way: Only encode the characters that have an HTML Name, with their HTML Name from the table in the link (and the symbols that do NOT have HTML **Name** should stay the same and not replaced with their HTML **Number**).

for example: I want the string  `& '` to be encoded to `&amp; '`, but the results I am getting are giving `&amp; &#39;`, it is converting a symbol that also does not have a HTML Name.

```
HttpUtility.HtmlEncode();
```

is encoding to both HTML Name and HTML Number..

**UPDATE:**
trying to use `Microsoft.Security.Application.Encoder.HtmlEncode` ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22451848/custom-htmlencode-with-html-entity-name-is-it-possible)) is giving also the same encoding results.

Any suggestions for other solution?

Comment: This question may be of help: [Stack Overflow: Can't include Microsoft.Security.Application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5979887/cant-include-microsoft-security-application)

Comment: Hmm, this did not help me because I'm not working on a website

Comment: Hmmmm, try to install `AntiXSSLibrary` via **NuGet**

Comment: @MatiCicero imported the dll and the implement worked, but it gives the same (unwanted) results as HttpUtility encoding

Answer (score 0):

> Any suggestions for other solution or a way to implement Microsoft.Security;?

Have you tried adding the System.Security dll manually?

References folder in the solution, rightclick, Add Reference.., Assemblies, Framework, browse to System.Security, check the box and press OK.

Now you should be able to add:

```
using System.Security
```

at the top of your C# file.

Comment: I imported AntiXss dll reference for it to work, but is giving the same (unwanted) results